# Custom Model Binder adds an extra error by itself when supplied with an array

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

This is a web api model binder rather than an MVC one.

It is pretty simple, it is a model binding for `int[]`, which I have implemented myself due to a slight logic difference:

```
public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(int[]))
    {
        return false;
    }

    ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

    // convert a value or an array of values into an int []
    List<int> convertedValues = new List<int>();

    if (val.RawValue is string)
    {
        int outInt;
        if (int.TryParse((string)val.RawValue, out outInt))
        {
            bindingContext.Model = new int[] { outInt };
            return true;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"The value {(string)val.RawValue} is not a valid Int32.");
        return false;
    }
    else if (val.RawValue is List<string>)
    {
        foreach (var str in (List<string>)val.RawValue)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"The value {str} is not a valid Int32.");
                return false;
            }

            int outInt;
            if (int.TryParse(str, out outInt))
            {
                convertedValues.Add(outInt);
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"The value {str} is not a valid Int32.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        bindingContext.Model = convertedValues.ToArray();
        return true;
    }

    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"The value is not a valid Int32.");
    return false;
}
```

It works great, except for one strange issue: If the type of the rawvalue is an array (e.g. user goes to `http://localhost/something?id=24&id=25&id=potato`) then in addition to my logic adding a model state error potato is not an integer, MVC also adds its own error saying the same thing, so I get 2 errors:

> "modelErrors": [ { "parameterName": "ids", "errors": [ "The value
>   potato is not a valid Int32.", "The value 'potato' is not valid for
>   Int32." ] } ] }

If they just provide one value, `something?id=potato` then the first bit of code runs, and adds a model error, and MVC *doesn't* add its own extra model error.

The question is, why is MVC adding an extra model error by itself, and how can I stop it?

The second error is added after the method completes, because when my separate validation attribute code runs, I can see an extra error has been added.

I have tried `bindingContext.ValidationNode.SuppressValidation = true;` but this did not work.

Any ideas?